# .xlsx file corrumption following streaming event

Tags: c#, excel-2007

I am using the EPPlus library to create an .xlsx file which I am then streaming to the browser.  To stream the code I am using:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = true;
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + Server.MapPath("xls/"+ download_results_filename));
            HttpContext.Current.Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("xls/" + download_results_filename));
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
```

My question is this.  If I use my code along with the library, save and open the document everything is fine.  However, when I create the file on the server and stream it to the user, using the code above, I get a corrupt file message with the additional ability to correct or recover the file, which I do and the file displays correct; so if using the octet stream method above to stream the file to the user corrupts the file how should I stream the Binary data to the user.  I want to keep the content type to 'application/octet-stream' as if I am specific about it being an excel spreadsheet I run into problems on the iPad.

Thanks

Comment: why do you use path from server in filename that is send to the client ? (in Content-Disposition header)

Comment: Otherwise it can't find the file.

Comment: that is true for TransmitFile, but not for Content-Disposition header, filename defined here is just something that will client (browser) use for default filename, but I am not sure that this is a reason for file corruption

Comment: No that is true Antonio.  I did notice however that on the iPad that if the filename in the content-disposition and transmitfile call were not the file would not get downloaded correct.  But as you also say, not the reason for the error that I am experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

Did you see this example?

http://epplus.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WebapplicationExample

It use this line

```
Response.BinaryWrite(pck.GetAsByteArray());
```